# Import issues with custom python package

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, module, package

I have a python package that is stubbed out like this:

```
<main package>
   |-> __init__.py
   <sub package1>
      |-> __init__.py
      |-> admin.py
      |-> <other python files>
   <sub package 2>
      |-> __init__.py
      |-> <other python files>
```

in the main package **init**.py I did the following:

```
import subpackage1
import subpackage2
__version__ = "1.2.1a"
```

When I go to use the package, I run into issue with imports

```
from mainpackage import subpackage1 # works 
admin = subpackage1.admin  #fails
from mainpackage.subpackage1 import admin # works
```

Should I be able to directly call the admin module from subpackage1? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `import admin` in `__init__.py` of the `subpackage1`.
After that the following code should work:

```
/main/subpackage1/__init__.py

import admin

/main/subpackage1/admin.py

def PrintAdmin():
    print 'Admin'

/some_other_module.py:

from main import subpackage1
admin = subpackage1.admin 
#Invoke some function from admin.py
admin.PrintAdmin() #RESULT: Admin
```

Comment: so for every module in the subpackage1 I would have to do an import in the __init__.py of subpackage?

Comment: You would have to. You may also `import main.subpackage1.admin as admin` and then in your code you can use `admin.PrintAdmin()`

Comment: I know no better way for static import. Would like to know as well

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misunderstood what you were asking, due to the way Python importing works, if you do

```
from mainpackage import subpackage1
```

All the items in `subpackage1` can be referenced without putting `mainpackage` in front of it, as opposed to if you were to do

```
import mainpackage
```

Comment: ok, i think I see what you are saying.  So I'm just misunderstanding imports?